# Creating a simple Authentication application in .NET Core application

Tags: asp.net, authentication, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, blazor

I am working on a Blazor app. I am new to .NET CORE and even newer to .NET CORE 3.0 Blazor. I want to implement a simple login authentication functionality.

I added ASP.NET CORE 3.0 Identity to my Blazor application but it added 5 extra packages and a plethora of .cs files and Pages. I do NOT need registration, social login or forgot password implementation which is a part of *Identity*.

Before CORE, I used MVC5. Over there, I used sessions in such a case. But Sessions are mostly discouraged. So, what I want is a clean and secure way to fulfill my, rather simple and short, requirement of Login functionality in an ASP.NET Core Blazor application.

Comment: How many days do you want to spend, and how much less security will you accept?  Just use Identity and be done with this.

Comment: See: A Demonstration of Simple Server-side Blazor Cookie Authentication http://blazorhelpwebsite.com/Blog/tabid/61/tagid/66/Blazor.aspx

Comment: Nowadays, OIDC is used with authorization_code + PKCE flow for protect SPA applications.

Comment: Plenty of examples of security that does not use identity: https://github.com/AdrienTorris/awesome-blazor#authentication